# DirectorySearcher returns ERROR_MORE_DATA

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I have developed an application that talks to the Directory Server and gets user information.

This application is a generic one and can talk to Active Directory or Any other Directory Services.

In one case where i use this application to read data from Radiant One VDS, the application fails with the `ERROR_MORE_DATA`. Following is the code that returns this error:

```
 try
{
  using (DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + server + "/" + basedn, username, pwd,AuthenticationTypes.None))
  {
    using (DirectorySearcher Searcher = new DirectorySearcher(de))
    {
      Searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user))";
      Searcher.ReferralChasing = ReferralChasingOption.All;
      Searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
      Searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberof");
      Searcher.PageSize = 1000;

      using (SearchResultCollection allUsers = Searcher.FindAll())
      {                            
        foreach (SearchResult user in allGroups)
        {
          .
          .
          .
          .
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
catch(System.Exception ex)
{
}
```

In the above code, `Searcher.FindAll()` returns `ERROR_MORE_DATA`. When i searched i found the [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/833789) article.

But, this article talks about .NET 1.0 and my application runs with .NET 3.5

Can you anyone please help me here? Is there any way to fix this without going for `DirectoryServices.Protocols`?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this issue comes in the following situation:-

If one or more entries are found in Network and the buffer size is not enough to hold it.
see [ERROR_MORE_DATA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370623(v=vs.85).aspx)

You just need to specify the size of buffer.
see: [specify the size of buffer in network call](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16113/Retreiving-a-list-of-network-computer-names-using?msg=2974626#xx2974626xx)